# Increase Phase Velocity by Losing Power

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waveguide

I just read some words from the book *Optical Waveguide Theory by Snyder, Allan W., p226*. It says that

> However, although it is possible for the phase velocity of a mode to exceed the maximum speed of light in  the cladding *(of waveguide)*, $c/n_cl$,  this cannot occur  without losing  power to radiation

My question is how to understand this? Why losing power can increase the phase velocity of the wave?